# Sending jQuery variable to php function

Tags: jquery, javascript

I'm sending the **x** jQuery variable to php file.

This is my jQuery with the ajax:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var x = jQuery('#sbering option:selected').val();
jQuery('#optionvalue').html(x);

  jQuery.ajax({
        url: frontEndAjax.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action':'my_ajax_function',
            'id' : x
        },
        success:function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        },
    });
});
```

This is the function where I'm sending the x variable:

```
function my_ajax_function() {

  if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {
    $aux = $_REQUEST['id'];
    echo "ID: " . $aux;
  }
  var_dump($aux);
...
```

instead of printing both $aux and var_dump($aux) on screen 
they're only visible in the console and $aux in php is Null.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When you say no result, do you mean it's literally returning `'No Result'` from your code, or something else? What does the request say in the console?

Comment: Add  wp_die() before close function "my_ajax_function()" other wise return o with result.

Comment: I finally have got some result, but now I'm getting the echo $_POST['id']; only in the console and not in php.

Comment: Your JavaScript is only logging the response to the console, why would it print to the screen? PHP will just return the result to the `success` callback function. Then you need to use JS to output the the HTML somewhere.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I need the jQuery variable x in php for some calculations.

Comment: So do the calculations in `my_ajax_function()` then in the `success` callback output the result to the page.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, I can't do it, because the value of x is Null in php. I also have tried to return the value of other variable that I need and send it to the jQuery function and do the calculations there, but it's value is 0...

Comment: Your problem could be that your server isn't populating $_REQUEST correctly.  You just can't trust that var.  Instead try $_GET since Jquery method is GET by default.

Comment: @PaulG., I've tried with POST and GET but I'm getting 0's in the console and nothing on screen.